# Triangulation of encoded points from Structured Light Scanning produces warped point cloud

Tags: opencv, 3d, triangulation, scanning, 3d-reconstruction

I've been trying to code a 3D scanner that uses structured light (one camera and projector only). I'm using Taubin and Moreno's software (at their [site](https://web.archive.org/web/20191021084042/http://mesh.brown.edu/calibration/software.html) that is somehow down right now, use wayback machine to check it out.) to obtain the projector intrinsics and extrinsics as a start, and the linear least squares triangulation method described [here](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2012/01/04/simple-triangulation-with-opencv-from-harley-zisserman-w-code/).

However, regardless of the objects scanned, the point clouds obtained are warped in a convex manner (see images below). This is most likely not a intrinsics/extrinsics/distortion parameter issue, as the same calibration parameters gives a proper point cloud when using the software linked above. I'm also inclined to say that my decoding process is not faulty, as the row and column correspondences appear to be correct (see below). Using a previously decoded dataset also gives the same issue.

```
def linearLS_triangulation(u_c, u_p, P_c, P_p, A, B):
    """
    Performs linear least squares triangulation via an overdetermined linear
    system
    
    Reference:
    http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~hartley/Papers/triangulation/triangulation.pdf
    """    
            
    A[0][0] = u_c[0]*P_c[2][0] - P_c[0][0]
    A[0][1] = u_c[0]*P_c[2][1] - P_c[0][1]
    A[0][2] = u_c[0]*P_c[2][2] - P_c[0][2]
    A[1][0] = u_c[1]*P_c[2][0] - P_c[1][0]
    A[1][1] = u_c[1]*P_c[2][1] - P_c[1][1]
    A[1][2] = u_c[1]*P_c[2][2] - P_c[1][2]
    A[2][0] = u_p[0]*P_p[2][0] - P_p[0][0]
    A[2][1] = u_p[0]*P_p[2][1] - P_p[0][1]
    A[2][2] = u_p[0]*P_p[2][2] - P_p[0][2]
    A[3][0] = u_p[1]*P_p[2][0] - P_p[1][0]
    A[3][1] = u_p[1]*P_p[2][1] - P_p[1][1]
    A[3][2] = u_p[1]*P_p[2][2] - P_p[1][2]
    B[0][0] = -(u_c[0] * P_c[2][3] - P_c[0][3])
    B[1][0] = -(u_c[1] * P_c[2][3] - P_c[1][3])
    B[2][0] = -(u_p[0] * P_p[2][3] - P_p[0][3])
    B[3][0] = -(u_p[1] * P_p[2][3] - P_p[1][3])

    # Use of the normal equation, np.linalg.lstsq also works!        
    w = np.linalg.inv(A.T.dot(A)).dot(A.T).dot(B)
    return w[:, 0]

def get_cam_points(decoded, K_c):
    """
    Get list of camera pixels that have a correspondence to projector pixels
    Returned in global coordinates, where world centre is centre of projection
    of the camera
    """
    [height, width] = np.nonzero(decoded[0])
    points_cam = np.zeros([3, height.shape[0]], dtype = np.float)
    K_c_inv = np.linalg.inv(K_c)
    
    for i in range(height.shape[0]):
        points_cam[:, i] = [width[i], height[i], 1]
    
    points_cam = np.dot(K_c_inv, points_cam)
    
    return points_cam

def get_proj_pixels(width_p, height_p, K_p, dist_p, R_p, T_p):
    """
    Passes the resolution of the projector along with the intrinsics and
    extrinsics, computing the mapping from projector pixels to the optical 
    rays returned in [x, y, z] for each pixel in the 'image'
    
    This assumes that the camera is the origin, with rotation and translation
    matrixes of the projector respect to that.
    """
    column_p = np.arange(width_p, dtype = np.float)
    row_p = np.arange(height_p, dtype = np.float)
    C, R = np.meshgrid(column_p, row_p)
    uv_p = np.zeros([np.ravel(C).shape[0], 1, 2], dtype = np.float)
    uv_p[:, 0, :] = np.c_[np.ravel(C),np.ravel(R)]

    uv_p = cv2.undistortPoints(uv_p, K_p, dist_p)
    uv_p = uv_p[:,0,:]
    uv_p = np.c_[uv_p, np.ones([np.ravel(C).shape[0]])]   
    uv_p = uv_p.transpose()
    
    uv_grid = np.zeros([3, height_p, width_p], dtype = np.float)
    uv_grid[0] = np.reshape(uv_p[0, :], [height_p, width_p])
    uv_grid[1] = np.reshape(uv_p[1, :], [height_p, width_p])
    uv_grid[2] = np.reshape(uv_p[2, :], [height_p, width_p])
    
    return uv_grid

def triangulate_all(decoded, P_c, P_p, dist_p, K_c, K_p, width_p, height_p):
    [height, width] = np.nonzero(decoded[0])
    points = np.zeros([3, height.shape[0]], dtype = np.float)
    points_cam = get_cam_points(decoded, K_c)
    points_proj = np.zeros([3, height.shape[0]], dtype = np.float)
    uv_grid = get_proj_pixels(width_p, height_p, K_p, dist_p, 
                              P_p[:, :3], P_p[:, 3].reshape(-1, 1))

    # Get list of projector pixels corresponding to non-zero camera pixels    
    for i in range(height.shape[0]):
        inter = decoded[:, height[i], width[i]]
        points_proj[:, i] = uv_grid[:, inter[1], inter[0]]
    
    A = np.zeros((4, 3), dtype = np.float)
    B = np.zeros((4, 1), dtype = np.float)  
    
    for i in range(height.shape[0]):
        points[:, i] = linearLS_triangulation(points_cam[:, i], 
                                                  points_proj[:, i], 
                                                  P_c, P_p, A, B)
    return points

print('Loading calibration parameters...')

calib_params = cv2.FileStorage('calibration.yml', cv2.FILE_STORAGE_READ)
dist_c = calib_params.getNode('cam_kc').mat()
dist_p = calib_params.getNode('proj_kc').mat()
K_c = calib_params.getNode('cam_K').mat()
K_p = calib_params.getNode('proj_K').mat()
R_p = calib_params.getNode('R').mat()
R_p = R_p.transpose() # Rotation matrix of projector with respect to camera origin
R_c = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
T_p = calib_params.getNode('T').mat()
T_c = np.array([0,0,0])

width_p = 1920
height_p = 1080

P_c = np.c_[R_c, T_c]
P_p = np.c_[R_p, T_p]

print('Loading color image...')
color = cv2.imread(scandir + 'Image01.jpg')
color = color/255

print('Loading decoded matrix...')
# A 2 x imgheight x imgwidth (in pixels) matrix, with the first channel being the column (x-direction)
# estimates and the second channel being the row (y-direction) pixel estimates of the projector.
# E.g. a pixel at point [300, 400] (Origin at top left of image!) would correspond to the projector 
# pixels of [16, 4] (Origin at top left). A zero would indicate the lack of correspondence for that 
# specific pixel
decoded = np.load('Decoded Matrix.npy')

points = triangulate_all(decoded, P_c, P_p, dist_p, K_c, K_p, 
                         width_p, height_p)
```

[Point cloud and original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCP3p.jpg)

[Another point cloud, and the decoded row and column estimates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmGLj.jpg)

Help would be greatly appreciated! At a loss of what to do.

Edit:
Got rid of the line normalizing the ray vectors

Comment: If i understand this line correctly, it normalizes rays to be L2 unit norm: `uv_p = np.divide(uv_p, np.linalg.norm(uv_p, axis = 1).reshape(-1, 1)) `.
Are you sure you need to perform it? Typically rays should be of the form `[x, y, 1]` (last component is always 1), and in fact below you only use (x, y) coordinates anyway.

Comment: Thanks for catching that vasiliykarasev! I meant to erase those lines both for the camera and projector rays but appeared to have missed one out. However, it doesn't seem to correct the warping, as I initially wrote the script without normalizing the rays.